# Unable to find element on closed window (NoSuchWindowError) - works with FF but not with IE

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My ruby script runs fine over *Firefox*, but gives the following over *Internet Explorer*:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok': Unable to find element on closed window (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:580:in `find_element_by'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:42:in `find_element'
    from D:/SMC/eclipse/SMC_workspace/LaunchBrowser/LaunchIE.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

My ruby script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
driver.get "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:id,"gbqfq")
```

Comment: Have you tried `"http://www.google.com"`? (perhaps FF fixes it automatically).

Comment: yup it worked; I used " https: // www .google.com "
Please add it to ans;
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `http://google.com` to `http://www.google.com`.

Perhaps FF fixes it automatically but IE doesn't...